# time stamp between Hive and Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I have a scenario where we have a timestamp field in the source file and getting loaded to the archive in text format and in the managed table in parquet format.
The difference we see is that the value between these two tables is off by 5 hours.

Any idea if this is something you guys cane across or is this a big with Cloudera?

Please let me know.

Comment: Please elaborate your questions a bit more. This is insufficient information to debug your problem. Most probably it's a timezone issue but more details about the issue will help to rectify it accurately.

Comment: @Eresh Kindly check my answer and upvote/accept, if it helps.

Comment: I want to correct something above. "Impala will add 5 hours to the timestamp, it will treat as a local time for impala." That is incorrect. Impala does nothing to the timestamp it reads it as written. The problem is that HIVE always wants to convert the TS to UTC based on the local TZ of the machine. Its HIVE that's changing the value not Impala. Nor does Impala "assume UTC" impala simply reads the value as written. For example if you write a TS with a time 08-24-2018 11:16:00 HIVE assumes that local timezone based on the machine, and then converts it to UTC and writes it. Impala just writes (

Answer (score 1):

As per `impala` document [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_timestamp.html), `impala` by default assumes UTC timezone for the data.

> Because Impala does not assume that `TIMESTAMP` values are in any
>   particular time zone, you must be conscious of the time zone aspects
>   of data that you query, insert, or convert.
>
> For consistency with Unix system calls, the `TIMESTAMP` returned by the
>   `now()` function represents the local time in the system time zone,
>   rather than in UTC. To store values relative to the current time in a
>   portable way, convert any `now()` return values using the
>   `to_utc_timestamp()` function first.

When working with hive, you may want to follow what the document suggest, but please note that there is a performance overhead with the solution. To avoid the performance overhead, suggest you to save the hive date in UTC timezone (if possible)

> If you have data files written by Hive, those `TIMESTAMP` values
>   represent the **local timezone** of the host where the data was written,
>   potentially leading to inconsistent results when processed by `Impala`.
>   To avoid compatibility problems or having to code workarounds, you can
>   specify one or both of these impalad startup flags:
>
> `-use_local_tz_for_unix_timestamp_conversions=true`
>
> `-convert_legacy_hive_parquet_utc_timestamps=true`
>
> Although `-convert_legacy_hive_parquet_utc_timestamps` is **turned off by default to avoid performance overhead**, where practical turn it on when
>   processing `TIMESTAMP` columns in Parquet files written by Hive, to
>   avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected behaviour when you use the timestamp in the hive, you have to set `convert_legacy_hive_parquet_utc_timestamps` globally.

Impala will add 5 hours to the timestamp, it will treat as a local time for impala. The easiest solution is to change the field type to string or subtract 5 hours while you are inserting in the hive.

There are a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556226/impala-timestamps-dont-match-hive-a-timezone-issue) on this already, check out.