# Different timestamp value in hive and impala

Tags: hive, impala

I hive one table and when I query it in `hive` it returns `2021-08-31 11:01:56` but in `Impala` it returns `2021-08-31 07:01:56`. How can I make impala read the correct timestamp which is the one in hive ?

Solution here: [Impala timestamps don't match Hive - a timezone issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556226/impala-timestamps-dont-match-hive-a-timezone-issue)

Comment: If it is Parquet, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33556226/2700344

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. I am closing the post.